# im completly stucked in richtextbox

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, richtextbox

i am using visual studio 2012 and of course c++.
i have assignment to wright something  like word-pad.
i found Richtextbox good option for me to use it as text-editor.but i cant use it.
can u plz help me and tell me which header i should include,what namespace and other stuffs.
msdn didnt help me at all :D
and i am using MFC app....and i use toolbox to create a Richtextbox.
i am really under pressure(i have 3 days only :D)
thanks guys

PS:plz show me a complete example(like hello world) that is workable.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't somewhere to come and get people to do your homework.  If you are coding and come across a problem you can't solve then search google, search msdn, search stackoverflow, and if you can't find an answer after all your searching then post a question about your issue with source code.

Comment: dude i dont want to solve my problem,i only need to know how it works,i cant start my work without a simple example like hello world

Comment: using System.Windows.Controls;  is the using directive you'll need, but IMO if you can't find out the using directive on your own you'll need to read up alot more before you can continue.  What type of application is it supposed to be? winforms? WPF?

Comment: im using mfc applications dialog based with some button and one big textbox.

Comment: Taken from MSDN post "1)       In Dialog editor, right click the rich edit control, add variable. In Add Member Variable Wizard, given a Variable Name, say richedit1, and press finish. Then we can using richedit1 to access the control as following:
 CString str;
richedit1.SetWindowTextW(L"Hello"); // write to rich edit
richedit1.GetWindowTextW(str);// read from rich edit"

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43ea3fdf-f374-498d-9b8c-791c707859f5/how-to-use-a-richtextbox-in-cpp is the source for the above comment.

Comment: using System.Windows.Controls doesnt work,i searched and i should add "PresentationFramework" in the reference to use "System.Windows.Controls" but i cant find it,can u help me?

Comment: Here's a link to something that might help, intialization for RichTextEdit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxtk3936.aspx I have had very little luck finding the correct includes. you might want to look at the superpad example listed in the answer by ScottMcP-MVP to find those if possible. Here's a direct link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177543(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample editor using the rich edit control in the "MFC Samples" of MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y8h3tk(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: i didnt understand what it said,there was not any sample that i can see

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sample I listed in your comments, it's a direct link to the example Scott posted, you'll have to download it and build it if you want to run it. try initializing the richtextedit and looking for the includes needed in that sample, if this helps and you accept this answer I'll edit accordingly and remove the comments.